# Repairing Mac OS X Leopard without Time Machine

Tags: macos, leopard

I did a dumb thing and accidentally overwrote my copy of /usr/bin/sqlite3 on my Mac OS X 10.5.8. I don't have a Time Machine backup so I can't grab the file from there. When I try to run Apache2, I'm getting the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

How can I retrieve or rebuild /usr/bin/sqlite3?

Edit: Before all of this, I ran the 10.5.8 Combo Update in case something on my system was corrupted.

Comment: have you tried running the 10.5.8 Combo Update? It should reinstall it (at least if it has been updated between 10.5.0 to 10.5.8)

Comment: Will this work, even though I'm already running at 10.5.8?

Comment: It is used if the installation is damaged, even if the requirement is between 10.5.0 and 10.5.7 I heard many people who used it on the same system version so it should work fine

Comment: For posterity: This solution worked for me!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the entire Mac OS X is the guaranteed way to ensure all system components are correctly installed.

Sometimes you can get away with running a Combo Updater (the 10.5.8 in your case), it can repair a slightly damaged (or corrupted) installation.

If you are unsure of why things are missing or damaged, better to reinstall or at least run a Repair Permissions in Disk Utility. System files should be protected from deleting and you don't know if other protections are missing or changed.

Comment: Just to be clear, the combo updater only repairs missing things if that specific thing has changed. In practice, each successive update changes more and more, but it's not as good as reinstalling the OS and then patching things. It's s nice trick when it works, but it's by luck and not by design that this works.

Comment: I wrote that in the comment above but I did not rewrite it in the answer. Wopps

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite version is outdated anyway. I suggest you go over here http://www.sqlite.org/ and download the current client. (Yes Apple is one of the sponsors. they use SQLite a lot for their apps, eg Mail for instance)

If you are looking for the framework, that is only included in the base installation. 
Have a look here for a similar problem and solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/251647/restore-sqlite3-on-mac-os-x-for-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to extract the file from your installer disc. You can either open the `.mpkg` and look for the specific installer `.pkg` and extract the contents wholesale out of the `.bom` archive

An alternative is that you can use a utility like Pacifist to do the job for you. (I've never used Pacifist, it costs a small amount of money).